# DateTimePicker con fecha, horas, minutos y segundos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetimepicker

estoy trabajando en un sistema de facturación en México utilizando React y MUI. Las guías de llenado del SAT en algunos campos te obligan a establecer un punto exacto de tiempo con este formato dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss, el problema es que no encuentro la manera de agregar un datetimepicker que contenga todo eso a la vez, El componente DateTimePicker de MUI esta muy feo, y el datepicker nativo me agrada pero solo he logrado que me permita elegir la fecha completa, las horas, minutos pero no los segundos ¿Hay alguna manera de lograrlo? Hasta ahora mi código esta así (tambien adjunto imagen del resultado):

```
<TextField
   id="datetime-local"
   label="Next appointment"
   type="datetime-local"
   defaultValue={ new Date() }
   InputLabelProps={{
     shrink: true,
   }}
 />
```

Muchas gracias de antemano[image: Esta imagen es una muestra de lo que tengo hasta ahora, nada mas falta que me permita elegir segundos]

Comment: Yo recién agregue un datetimepicker a un fullcalendar y al momento de modificar la fecha me pone el formato exactamente como tu lo requieres YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss en el input.  Espero que ya hayas resuelto este inconveniente.  Aqui mi problema es que yo quisiera que fuera para la hora 00:00:00 .  Saludos

Answer (score 0):

ya pasó bastante tiempo, pero aquí les publico la manera como solucioné mi problema:

```
<TextField
   label="Fecha y hora de salida o llegada *"
   type="datetime-local"
   defaultValue={moment().format("yyyy-MM-DDThh:mm:ss")}
   color='primary'
   InputLabelProps={{
     shrink: true,
   }}
   fullWidth
 />
```

Lo que hice fue instalar la librería Moment.js que contiene métodos para obtener la hora con el formato indicado. En este caso al atributo defaultValue le pasé como valor lo que retorna la instrucción moment().format("yyyy-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"). Lo importante es que este valor contenga este formato yyyy-MM-DDThh:mm:ss para que el input permita seleccionar también los segundos.

Les dejo una captura[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]